# Speed up os.walk while listing files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I have a directory structure like this:

```
test/A/foo/
|-foo1
|-foo2
|-bar1
|-bar2
test/B/foo/
|-foo1
|-foo2
|-bar1
|-bar2
test/C/foo/
|-foo1
|-foo2
|-bar1
|-bar2
```

I know only that the toplevel `test` directory will be present. I don't know the directorie names `A`, `B` beforehand but I know that if they are present they will have a subfolder called `foo`.

I want to get a list of all filenames matching a pattern from `test/{A, B, C...}/foo`

I'm using `os.walk` on the `test` directory like so:

```py
files_list = [file for _, _, files in os.walk("test") for file in files if re.match(r"^foo", file)]
```

But this is a bit slow even when the directory structure is small.

Is there a way to speed this up or do something differently to speed it up?

Thanks!

Comment: [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)?

Comment: Side comment, why `f"{file}"` instead of just `file`?  Seems like a useless use of f-strings.

Comment: Could `test/A` have other subfolders besides `foo`, that you would want to skip?

Comment: @John Gordon re. f-string fixed. second question: yes it can @deceze thanks seems like using glob is already an improvement over os.walk I'm using the following pattern `test/*/foo/*` and os.path.isfile to check if they are files and os.path.basename to get the filenames.

Comment: `os.walk` is considered a little old compared to `pathlib.walk`, but we'd need to know more about what's "slow" in your context (is the problem that it's collecting all the names in a given directory before returning any, meaning latency as opposed to absolute time for a completed walk? -- many of the performance characteristics depend on the directory sizes, which you're saying nothing about)

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest I can imagine:

```
import os
import os.path
for entry in os.listdir('test'):
  print(os.path.join('test', entry, 'foo'))
```

You may want to call `os.path.isdir(...)` before printing.

`glob.glob` is implemented in terms of `os.scandir`, which is similar to `os.listdir`, but may be faster on some filesystems and use cases because it does streaming output.

`os.walk` does lots of unnecessary work (including a recursive directory scan) for your use case.

Comment: `os.listdir` is itself not the fastest available interface, because it processes the whole directory before returning anything at all, vs being able to return names to the caller incrementally as the OS kernel feeds them back (granted, whether this is a win depends on details; it's particularly likely to be a net benefit over a slow network filesystem). Compare to `os.scandir` (which also returns stat data so someone can distinguish files vs directories &c without needing a second syscall; the OP's original code ignores directories, which your answer currently doesn't).